# How to read from multiplexer with python I2C

Tags: python

Based on the following links:
https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=83918&p=541562&hilit=TCA9548A#p541562
https://github.com/kizniche/Mycodo/issues/43#issuecomment-156718451

I have created the followingÑ:

Multiplexer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Change channel of TCA9548A
# Example: sudo ./multiplexer_channel.py 0

import smbus
import time
import sys

I2C_address = 0x77
I2C_bus_number = 1
I2C_ch_0 = 0b00000001
I2C_ch_1 = 0b00000010
I2C_ch_2 = 0b00000100
I2C_ch_3 = 0b00001000
I2C_ch_4 = 0b00010000
I2C_ch_5 = 0b00100000
I2C_ch_6 = 0b01000000
I2C_ch_7 = 0b10000000

def I2C_setup(i2c_channel_setup):
    bus = smbus.SMBus(I2C_bus_number)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_address,i2c_channel_setup)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print "TCA9548A I2C channel status:", bin(bus.read_byte(I2C_address))

I2C_setup(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

and 
index2.py

```
from tentacle_pi.BMP180 import BMP180
import time
bmp = BMP180(0x70,"/dev/i2c-1")


for x in range(0,1005):
        print "temperature: %s" % bmp.temperature()
        print "pressure: %s" % bmp.pressure()
        print "altitude: %s" % bmp.altitude()
        print
        time.sleep(2)
```

If I execute the first file with parameters 0 to 7 (multiplexer ports), I get always a connection time out.

Please note I am using a raspberry PI 3 and everything is connected.

If I execute the 2nd file, I GET readings, but they are always misleading (fixed readings), and btw, I think the second file will not work if I have many sensors(BMP180)

EDIT1:
1. When we try i2cdetect y, we get nothing.
2. We found another Pythong program to work with the multiplexerÑ

```
# coding=utf-8

import argparse
import smbus
import time


class TCA9548A(object):
    def __init__(self, bus, address=0x70, ):
        self.i2c_address = address
        self.i2c_bus = bus
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(self.i2c_bus)

    def setup(self, channel):
        try:
            self.bus.write_byte(self.i2c_address, channel)
            return 1, "Success"
        except Exception as msg:
            return 0, "Fail: {}".format(msg)

    def read(self):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return self.bus.read_byte(self.i2c_address)


def menu():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Select I2C address and channel of TCA9548A I2C multiplexer')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--address', metavar='ADDRESS', type=int,
                        help='I2C address of the multiplexer, only last two digits, (ex. enter "70" if 0x70)',
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bus', metavar='BUS', type=int,
                        help='I2C bus of the multiplexer',
                        required=True)
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('-c', '--channel', metavar='CHANNEL', type=int,
                       help='Channel to be activated with the multiplexer')
    group.add_argument('-r', '--read', action='store_true',
                       help='Only read multiplexer and return channel number')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    i2c_address = int(str(args.address), 16)
    multiplexer = TCA9548A(args.bus, i2c_address)
    if args.channel:
        multiplexer.setup(args.channel)
    read_response = multiplexer.read()
    print("TCA9548A I2C channel status: {} (channel {})".format(bin(read_response), read_response))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

When we try to execute it like this:

```
sudo python index3py -a 70 -b 1
```

we also get a connection timeout

I am starting to believe that maaybe we have something wrongly connected.

We used adafruit wiring sample

EDIT2: coming with pics

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit3:
I restarted the PI, and now I can see the i2c on 77 address.

However I am getting misleading results, I tried all 7 channels with the same program (index2.py)changed 70 to 77. and I get always a temperature which makes no sense.

```
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 0
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b11111000 (channel 248)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.599998474
pressure: 40287
altitude: -31.4230690002

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 40183
altitude: -31.5887317657

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 40281
altitude: -37.2313270569

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 40284
altitude: -34.078414917

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 1
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b1 (channel 1)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 40166
altitude: -31.7548980713

temperature: -52.4000015259
pressure: 40163
altitude: -34.5762786865

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 2
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b0 (channel 0)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 28375
altitude: 1204.44226074

temperature: -52.4000015259
pressure: 28303
altitude: 1222.52453613

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 3
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b0 (channel 0)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 28304
altitude: 1205.19128418

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 28301
altitude: 1222.90002441

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 4
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b100 (channel 4)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 40136
altitude: -46.9332351685

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 40116
altitude: -47.5958938599

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 5
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b101 (channel 5)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 40185
altitude: -46.9332351685

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 40136
altitude: -47.0986480713

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 6
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b0 (channel 0)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 28365
altitude: 1216.15002441

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 28297
altitude: 1215.96289062

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index3.py -a 77 -b 1 -c 7
TCA9548A I2C channel status: 0b0 (channel 0)
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.p
python: can't open file 'index2.p': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ sudo python index2.py
temperature: -125.699996948
pressure: 28368
altitude: 1219.89953613

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 28283
altitude: 1219.71179199

temperature: -52.5
pressure: 28353
altitude: 1219.71179199

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2.py", line 11, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
pi@pi1:~/Documents/NodeJSProjects/PythonTests $ ^C
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and specify what you have connected to the I2C bus and how?

Comment: taking pictures, uploading in a second.  Basically we have a DHT11 on the GPIO, and then on the i2c bus we have a multiplexer TCA9548A, then on that multiplexer, we have 2 BMP180 sensors. We want to measure up to 8 BMP180 sensors with 1 raspberry and the multiplexer.

Comment: Edit1 posted, edit2 coming

Comment: There is no point running the Python scripts until the multiplexor is visible with `i2cdetect -y 1`.

Comment: please read Edit3, we restarted the pi and then the i2c shows address 77, however the sensor readings are misleadings, we pasted the entire command line.

Comment: Select channel 0 on the multiplexor (write 1 to it).  Then do an `i2cdetect -y 1`.  Do you see the multiplexor and the BMP on the bus?

Comment: we only see oe address, 77. should we see two or more ddepending on the sensors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50212/discussion-between-gina-and-joan).

Answer (score 1):

Rather create aditional i2c busses. It is much faster.

https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer with a link; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.